Pandas pd.readexcel not able to read cell values starting with "#" (Formula Errors)
I am trying to read excel file using pandas pd.read_excel and data in cells contains text values as formula errors. My requirement is to read the formula errors as text and not replace it with NA
Example:
#NA, #DIV/0! #Value
While reading this data using pd.read_excel all the data is converted to NA instead of reading the data as is.
I did try using openpyxl but for my overall requirement,  pandas read excel is apt because I get excel files with different formats.
Code:
import pandas as pd

xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('Book1.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheet_name ='Sheet1' ,engine_kwargs={"values_only":True})

Source:
1,0, #DIV/0!(Formula Error), #DIV/0! (Text)
Result:
LHS  RHS  Formula  Ftext
0    1    0      NaN    NaN

#NA should be interpreted as NaN, but not #DIV/0!/#Value
If you don't want read_excel to parse NaNs you have several options:
pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx', na_filter=False)

Which will keep all strings intact (including empty strings).
Or a combination of keep_default_na and na_values. For example to ignore everything as NaN except empty strings:
pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx',  keep_default_na=False, na_values=[''])


I have tested all possible combinations for the kwargs, but is not of any help.
Upon investigating i have found out that in site packages there values are hardcoded into a variable and then made NA
openpyxl/cell/cell.py:ERROR_CODES = ('#NULL!', '#DIV/0!', '#VALUE!', '#REF!', '#NAME?', '#NUM!',
Binary file openpyxl/cell/pycache/cell.cpython-312.pyc matches
Binary file openpyxl/formula/pycache/tokenizer.cpython-312.pyc matches
openpyxl/formula/tokenizer.py:    ERROR_CODES = ("#NULL!", "#DIV/0!", "#VALUE!", "#REF!", "#NAME?",
Need to override the variable

I also have all possible excel combinations as source files xls, xlsx , xlsb, xlsm etc... hence i am using pd.read_excel as it supports multiple engines

logic is hardcoded in source file the below file
pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py
def _convert_cell(self, cell) -> Scalar:
    from openpyxl.cell.cell import (
        TYPE_ERROR,
        TYPE_NUMERIC,
    )
    if cell.value is None:
        return ""  # compat with xlrd
    elif cell.data_type == TYPE_ERROR:
        return np.nan
    elif cell.data_type == TYPE_NUMERIC:
        val = int(cell.value)
        if val == cell.value:
            return val
        return float(cell.value)
    
    return cell.value

